# Upgrading Drupal from 6 to 7 results in double slash being present in image file paths

Tags: media, uri

After upgrading from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 I noticed that my image paths now have a double slash like this:

/files/sites/default//filename.jpg

I was thinking of running a simple find and replace in the database, but I'm sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 3):

I migrated my website from an old domain to a new one and this issue came up. Apparently, you should define new paths for website media (e.g. images) here:

`http://youwebsite.com/?q=admin/config/media/file-system`

There are two paths that must be specified. In my case,

Private: `sites/youwebsite.com/private`

Public: `sites/youwebsite.com/files`

Comment: Very interesting - I don't think I thought of that at the time that I posted this question, but it makes sense.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't upgrade from Drupal 6 to 7 so this solution might or not might work in that case. Performing find and replace might do the job too, but I guess when you are manipulating the Drupal database directly and in the large-scale, you are probably on the wrong path.